# My ajax Drupal form shows up old values

Tags: forms, drupal

I have developed ajax drupal and add a form (textfield and button) in it using #ajax key and callback function where I do my process and return my form new element.

So when I starts adding my data form, it works fine for me and *form_state['values']* are updated fine.

The problem here is when I reload my form and I add some data, *form_state['values']* are not the same in my form fields.

Here is my code:

```
function my_horoscope_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['admin/horoscopes'] = array(
    'title' => 'Horoscopes',
    'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_horoscope_admin_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('Administer site configuration '),
    //'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
return $items;
```

}

```
function my_horoscope_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {

$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes'] = array(
    '#type'        => 'fieldset',
    '#title'       => t('Add horoscopes'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collaspsed'  => TRUE,
);
$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['name'] = array(
    '#type'            => 'textfield',
    '#title'           => t('Horoscope name'),
    '#default_value'   => t('Horoscope name'),
    '#size'            => 20,
    '#maxlength'       => 60,
    '#required'        => FALSE,
);
$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['beginning_date_rang'] = array(
    '#type'      => 'date',
    '#title'     => t('Horoscope beginning date rang'),
    '#description'      => t('Set the beginning date rang of this horoscope.'),
    '#required'  => FALSE,
);
$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['ending_date_rang'] = array(
    '#type'      => 'date',
    '#title'     => t('Horoscope ending date rang'),
    '#description'      => t('Set the ending date rang of this horoscope.'),
    '#required'  => FALSE,
);
$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['add_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Add this horoscope'),
    '#submit' => array(''),
    '#ajax'   => array(
        'event' => 'click',
        'callback' => 'add_horoscope_ajax_process',
        'wrapper'  => 'add_horoscope_wrapper',
    ),
);
$form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['adding_horoscope_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="add_horoscope_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

return $form;
}

function add_horoscope_ajax_process ($form, &$form_state) {

if (isset($form_state['values'])) {

    if (isset($form_state['values']['name']) AND $form_state['values']['name'] != '') {
        $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    }
    if (isset($form_state['values']['beginning_date_rang']) AND $form_state['values']['beginning_date_rang'] != '') {
        $beginning_date_rang = $form_state['values']['beginning_date_rang'];
        $beginning_date_rang1 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $beginning_date_rang['year'], $beginning_date_rang['month'], $beginning_date_rang['day']);
    }
    if (isset($form_state['values']['ending_date_rang']) AND $form_state['values']['ending_date_rang'] != '')       {
        $ending_date_rang = $form_state['values']['ending_date_rang'];
        $ending_date_rang1 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $ending_date_rang['year'], $ending_date_rang['month'], $ending_date_rang['day']);
    }
    // Prepare record to add
    $record = array(
        'h_name'       => $name,
        'h_date_begin' => $beginning_date_rang1,
        'h_date_end'   => $ending_date_rang1,
    );
    // Add the record
    $res = drupal_write_record('my_horoscope_structure', $record);
    if($res != FALSE) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Horoscope @name is inserted successfully!', array('@name' => $name)));
    }

}
// return $form
return $form['settings']['horoscopes']['add_horoscopes']['adding_horoscope_wrapper'];
```

}

Comment: When you work with ajax, it retrieve the form from cache. To see latest changes, you need to retrieve the form from cache programatically, modify it and update in cache again.

Comment: you are right but in my case there was redundancy in array keys names and here is the solution https://www.drupal.org/node/2334715#comment-9135891

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you!